# Discrete Energy for a Particle In a 1D Box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I was taught that a particle in a 1D Box can have only discrete energies proportional to the square of the excited level of the particle. Now, for example, lets say that the particle has 1 unit of energy in the ground state. Obviously, it has 4 units of energy in first excited state. What if I have given 3 units of energy to the particle and kept it in the potential well? It cannot lose energy, right? Does superposition of two states happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units of energy you refer to are for the steady state solution.  As you have correctly guessed, the superposition
$$
\Psi(x,t)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\Psi_1(x,t)+e^{i\phi}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\Psi_4(x,t)
$$
(where $\phi$ is an arbitrary phase)
has *average* energy of $3$ units:
$$
\langle E\rangle =\frac{1}{3}\times 1+\frac{2}{3}\times 4=3\, ,
$$
but it is not steady state solution (i.e. not an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian).

Answer (score 0):

If it has one unit of energy and the second state has 4 and you give it three a transition can occur.

If you give it an amount of energy that is less than that needed to arrive at the second level the particle does not absorb the energy, the same way an electron in an atom does not absorb a photon that does not have the energy corresponding to a transition.

Obviously, this does not take into account a lot of factors: the width of the transition, transitions that occur in two (or more) steps